# Autodesk-Forge Hide Properties in Properties Inspector

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have implemented the custom properties discussed [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/05/adding-custom-meta-properties-to-the-viewer-property-panel.html).  While this example code is very helpful for adding properties that were not in the model, I cannot find any code that will allow me to remove/hide properties that were a part of the model except for the Forge RCDB examples found [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs), which implements an entirely separate DB.

I am hoping that it is possible to display properties from the model, but to hide those that are not necessary and to add custom properties as shown in the adding custom meta properties example.

Is this possible? If so can you assist me in understand how to hide the specific properties I am hoping to hide?

If is it not possible, is the best guide for adding a parallel external properties DB the Forge RCDB examples?

EDIT...
I implemented the custom properties panel and it adds the "Customization" category and then the "Node" attribute.  My question is... how can I hide attributes that were part of the model like "Thermal Mass","Absorptance", etc.

[image: properties panel example]

Thanks...
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to customize the Property Panel, right? If so, you can create a customized Property Panel, and use this one to override the default one, you can refer the code at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/blob/master/src/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.PropertyPanel/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.PropertyPanel.js .

Hope it helps.

Edited: If you want to remove/hide some properties, you can just remove them by calling API PropertyPanel.removeProperty() defined as follow:

```
enter   /**
* Removes a property from this panel.  The property is defined by its name, value, and category.
*
* @param {string} name - The name of the property to remove.
* @param {string} value - The value of the property to remove.
* @param {string} category - The category of the property to remove.
* @param {Object=} [options] - An optional dictionary of options.  Currently unused.
* @returns {boolean} - true if the property was removed, false otherwise.
*/
PropertyPanel.prototype.removeProperty = function (name, value, category, options) {
  var property = { name: name, value: value, category: category };
  var element = this.tree.getElementForNode(property);
  if (element) {
    delete this.highlightableElements[this.tree.delegate().getTreeNodeId(property)];
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

Check https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.js for details.

Comment: Thanks for this code.  I implemented and adjusted my question above.  I am really interested in removing existing attributes.  Thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer, in short, you can use PropertyPanel.removeProperty() to remove existing attributes.